# Need to grep data between line [Oct 13 2015, 16:10:16] and [Oct 13 2015, 16:10:20] using grep or awk or perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk, grep

I need to grep data between line [Oct 13 2015, 16:10:16] and [Oct 13 2015, 16:10:20] using grep or awk or perl

[Oct 13 2015, 16:10:16]
  starting script1
  script1 in progess

---

---

etc

[Oct 13 2015, 16:10:20]
  starting script2
  script2 in progess

---

---

etc

Comment: Is the problem that you have a text file where the lines begin with dates in the format you specified, such as a logfile, and you want to grep out a particular range?  (Could you edit the question a little bit to be clearer?)

If that is the case, you could do worse than just grepping out "[Oct 13 2015, 16:10:" and dealing with the seconds you don't want.  Or you can add the necessary regex to make it more specific - something like [16|17|18|19|20]. egrep uses regexes, but you have to work a little bit to escape them to get them past the shell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you don't need the regex, you could check equality, but you put regex in your tags...

```
perl -e '$show=0; while (<STDIN>) { $show = 1 if $_ =~ /^\[Oct 13 2015, 16:10:16\]/; print $_ if $show; $show = 0 if $_ =~ /^\[Oct 13 2015, 16:10:20\]/; }'  < log
```